# How to use 'Controller as' with $http in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to load some data through $http to prefill a profile form. Unfortunately all the examples I find online use the $scope-approach rather than 'Controller as'-approach (which I'm using to make future transition to Angular 2 easier). These examples assign the $http response to the '$scope' variable, which is not possible when using 'this'.

After a lot of fiddling I managed to get it to work by adding a temp variable

```
var temp = this;
```

to which I can assign the $http response when it successfully returns.

```
angular.module('angularUserApp')

.factory('ajax',['$http',function($http){
  return {
    getProfile: function(){
      return  $http.get('/ajax/user/profile')
        .then(function(response){
          return response.data.data.profile;
        });
      }
    }
}])

.controller('userProfileCtrl', ['ajax', function (ajax) {
  var temp = this;
  ajax.getProfile().then(function(response){
    temp.profile = response;
  });
}]);
```

Is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: That temp variable is pretty standard for the controllerAs syntax, although I've usually seen it named something like `vm` or `ctrl`.  Basically after `var ctrl = this;`, the `ctrl` refers to the controller, which will hold the `$scope` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach for using `controllerAs` is correct. Just a few advices though, better alias the `this` to a variable `vm`, which stands for `viewModel` instead of `temp`, and name your service semantically: `userService` instead of `ajax`:

```
angular.module('angularUserApp')
 .factory('userService', function ($http){
  return {
    getProfile: function () {
      return $http.get('/ajax/user/profile')
        .then(function (response){
          return response.data.profile;
        });
      }
    }
})

.controller('userProfileCtrl', function (userService) {
  var vm = this;
  userService.getProfile().then(function (response) {
    vm.profile = response;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, good to hear this is the standard approach! I have changed the variable names as suggested.

Answer (score -2):

One of the design ideas of angular is that you can use `$scope`. Simply inject `$scope` into your controller, like you did with your `ajax` service and set the profile response to the `$scope` variable (`$scope.profile = response;`).

As a result you would get something like:

```
angular.module('angularUserApp')

.factory('ajax',['$http',function($http){
  return {
    getProfile: function(){
      return  $http.get('/ajax/user/profile')
        .then(function(response){
          return response.data.data.profile;
        });
      }
    }
}])

.controller('userProfileCtrl', ['ajax', '$scope', function (ajax, $scope) {
  ajax.getProfile().then(function(response){
    $scope.profile = response;
  });
}]);

// In your template
<div ng-controller="userProfileCtrl">
    <div ng-bind="profile.name"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A lot of people believe that using `controllerAs` and `this` is better practice. [Example](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/).

Comment: 'Controller as' approach is as valid as $scope in modern Angular, please spend some time reading on it.

Comment: @AdamZerner you're right, shouldn't have mentioned avoiding `this`.